Xcode 16.2 in MacOs 15.1 quits everytime I open it
xcode version: 16.2 
macos verison: 15.1 Beta (24B5009l) 
chip: Apple M2 Pro 
problem: when opening xcode, it quits everytime i've open it, showing the error message: "xcode quits unexpectedly" 
current attempts: "have reinstalled xcode from appstore, but still doesn't work
\
paste bin log:
https://pastebin.com/FjD2xzyK


I believe that this problem might caused due to my macos is at 15.1 beta, I would try to downgrade my system to macos 13 or 14.

macOS 15.1 is stable, why not just update to this version?
